# script for auto opening directories (mac os x) and creating m3u playlists

Tags: macos, bash, itunes

Imagine that you have some directories containing both `mp3` files and sub-directories, also containing `mp3` files, like:

```
/music/band1/
/music/band2/
/music/band2/dir1/
/music/band2/dir2/
/music/band3/dir1/
/music/band3/dir2/
/music/band4/
...
```

I would like to create a `.m3u` file in every directory containing `mp3` files - so for example:

```
/music/band1/band1.m3u
/music/band2/band2.m3u
/music/band2/dir1/dir1.m3u
/music/band2/dir2/dir2.m3u
/music/band3/dir1/dir1.m3u
/music/band3/dir2/dir2.m3u
/music/band4/band4.m3u
```

The name of `.m3u` file will be the directory name in which the `.m3u` is created. (This is just an example directory structure.)

I hope it is clear :)

So far I have this to generate `m3u` files from `*.mp3` files, but only in the actual directory, and name it by directory.

```
#!/bin/bash\
ls | grep -i mp3 > filelist.txt
mv filelist.txt filelist.m3u
FOLDERNAME=${PWD##*/}
echo $FOLDERNAME
mv filelist.m3u $FOLDERNAME.m3u
```

What should be added to have it look recursively into every subdirectory of `/music`, and if there is another sub-sub directory, also look there? Then, execute the `m3u`-making script in each sub-directory?

Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 7):

This should take care of the whole thing for you (no need for the script).

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -execdir bash -c 'file="{}"; printf "%s\n" "${file##*/}" >> "${PWD##*/}.m3u"' \;
```

Comment: hi Dennis, I pasted your command into terminal but unfortunately it is not working, the error messages are(so long so just a beginning): bash: ${PWD##*/}.m3u: ambiguous redirect
as:file(You) Can't open source file for input! No such file or directory.
as:file(Are.mp3) Can't open source file for input! No such file or directory.
bash: ${PWD##*/}.m3u: ambiguous redirect
bash: You.mp3: command not found
bash: ${PWD##*/}.m3u: ambiguous redirect

bash: box.mp3: command not found
bash: bloom.mp3: command not found
bash: tea.mp3: command not found

Comment: @Ondrej: I'm sorry, I forgot some quotes. Please try my revised command.

Comment: Dennis - you are just a professional hacker! :) thank you, now it is working!

Comment: @Ondrej: I'm glad it's working for you. If you found it helpful, please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: any chance of a similar script that searches for both .m4a and .mp3 and generates a list for each "band*" folder that includes all sue-dir files in that one list? For example the ./music dir should include the band1.m3u and band2.m3u etc (no playlists in the sub-dirs)